# How to package, compress and deploy binaries as zip/tar.gz from a github repo with maven/travis to bintray.com generic repo

Tags: java, maven, github, travis-ci, bintray

Since Github disabled the downloads, we need to use a new service (like Bintray.com) for publishing our binaries. For our usecase I need to build a package (using appassembler-maven-plugin), then zip and tar.gz this build and deploy it to bintray.

It would be nice if a nightly builds will be shipped by travis and releases from hand with the mvn release plugin.

Currently the pom looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com/d0x/fromGithubToBintray</url>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/d0x/fromGithubToBintray.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:d0x/fromGithubToBintray.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Christian Schneider</name>
            <url>https://github.com/d0x</url>
            <id>d0x</id>
        </developer>
    </developers>

<!--    <distributionManagement> -->
<!--        <repository> -->
<!--            <id>bintray</id> -->
<!--            <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/d0x/fromGithubToBintray/downloads</url> -->
<!--        </repository> -->
<!--    </distributionManagement> -->


    <properties>
        <mainClass>fromGithubToBintray.Main</mainClass>

        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ... -->        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- To build a clean binary pacakge to distribute -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                            <name>fromGithubToBintray</name>
                        </program>
                    </programs>

                    <extraJvmArguments>-Djava.awt.headless=true</extraJvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- To specify the Java Version -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                    <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How to tune the pom file to do that?

**Reproduce:**

I uploaded the small example to github: https://github.com/d0x/fromGithubToBintray

To exectue it do the following:

1. git clone https://github.com/d0x/fromGithubToBintray.git
2. cd fromGithubToBintray
3. mvn clean package appassembler:assemble
4. chmod +x target/appassembler/bin/fromGithubToBintray
5. ./target/appassembler/bin/fromGithubToBintray

This should print `You did it!`. Now the goal is to upload compress and upload this appassembler folder to bintray.

**Research done:**

- [This tutorial](http://veithen.blogspot.de/2013/05/github-bintray-maven-release-plugin.html) shows how to use Bintray.com to publish to a Maven Repository.
- Also I saw that the Netty project host [its downloads](http://netty.io/downloads.html) on bintray. But in their Poms either in Jenkins I don't see bintray related stuff.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Bintray does not support SNAPSHOTs (Bintray is for releases only). What you need is an Artifactory+Bintray combo, that deploys snapshots to Artifactory, and once in a while (when you deside), releases a 'production-ready' version to Bintray.

Depending on the nature of your project you might be qualified to a free account on [oss.jfrog.org](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26083425). The requirement is that your deliverable is an open-source library/product, which is included in JCenter.

Pushing from Artifactory to Bintray is a really simple process, you can perform it just by clicking a button in Artifactory UI or by performing a REST call. Just remember - it must be a release, not a SNAPSHOT.

There are number of ways to convert a SNAPSHOT to release, which include changing versions in POM by hand, Maven Release Plugin, and others.
When you use oss.jfrog.org as your Artifactory server, it includes a special plugin, which converts SHAPSHOTs to releases and deploys to Bintray in one go.

Comment: That sounds good. It is an oss project. Never thought about oss.jfrog.org. I will give it a try.

Comment: Is it also possible to deploy *.tar.gz or *.zip (with the executables build by appassembler) to artifactory? Or do I need to stick to the Maven Repository layout (that shipps, POMs, WARs and JARs...)?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider yes it is possible to deploy a archive like this to artifactory. You can deploy it with or without the Maven Artifact.

Comment: @ReneHerget in the meanwhile i tried artifactory for myself. On the deploy option on the web ui you can upload normal files. Just don't check the maven checkbox. http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/download/attachments/25068007/image2013-4-11%2014%3A24%3A17.png?version=1&modificationDate=1365679481000&api=v2 But somehow i miss a running example that integrates everything

Comment: Of course you can deploy any files to Artifactory. Maven layout is the only layout the release functionality works with, but if you release by your own means, you are not limited to any layout. You can even [create your own layouts](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts).

Answer (score 3):

I think there are 2 ways to deploy your zip/tar.gz files to bintray.com.

**1. Upload over CI**

You can upload generic files to bintrac.com with curl.

```
curl -T <FILE.EXT> -u$USER:<API_KEY> https://api.bintray.com/content/$USER/generic/<UR_COOL_PACKAGE_NAME>/<VERSION_NAME>/<FILE_TARGET_PATH>
```

You can build your project over maven with a CI/travis and upload a specified file with curl. It should be possible with travis. See [here](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/ci-environment/)

**2. Deploy with Maven**

With maven you can deploy a specified file like a *.zip with mvn [deploy:deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html). Maybe this is a solution for you?

**EDIT after answer**

To create a *.zip archive you can use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

**1. Add maven-assembly-plugin to pom**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**2. Create configuration file**

I created for you a small example. it will compress the bin folder from your appassembler target.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>distribution</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target/appassembler/bin</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

**3. Execute maven**

Command: mvn clean appassembler:assemble package

**4. Upload generic file**

To upload your generic file with maven. You should have a look to [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html)
or you use the mvn [deploy:deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) plugin. If you want use this, it should look like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <goals>
        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <repositoryId>release</repositoryId>
        <packaging>zip</packaging>
        <generatePom>false</generatePom>
        <url>http://repository-url</url>
        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <file>target/filename.zip</file>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
<distributionManagement>
<repository>
    <id>releases</id>
    <name>My Artifactory-... server</name>
    <url>http://url-to-repository</url>
</repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

In my case, my settings.xml from maven looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <username>my-user</username>
            <password>my-password</password>
            <id>releases</id>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>releases</id>
                    <name>Name</name>
                    <url>http://serverurl</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <id>artifactory</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

if you execute now **mvn clean appassembler:assemble package** and then **mvn deploy:deploy-file** you will create a archive and upload it to your maven repository.

Comment: Hi, ty for the suggestion. But still I need to generate the zip and tar and somehow ship it to bintray. That isn't pointed out in your answer. Smth. like how to configure maven that it's release creates a new package in bintray.